# Checkstyle error for protected variable in abstract classes

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm kind of new to java and I'm facing an issue with protected variable in an abstract class. I've added the implementation below:

Abstract class:

```
public abstract class blah1 implements blah {
   protected variable1
   //// stuff///
}
```

sub class:

```
public class blah2 extends blah1 {
   ///uses variable1///
}
```

Checkstyle says I should convert the variable to private and then use get/set methods. But how do I accomplish this within an abstract-class/sub-class situation?

Comment: your subclasses inherit the get/set methods, why would there be a problem with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make variable private in parent class, then add getter and setter

```java
public abstract class blah1 {
  private int variable;

  public int getVariable() {
    return variable;
  }

  public void setVariable(int variable) {
    this.variable = variable;
  }
  //// stuff///
}
```

How to use it in the child class. Note the [super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) keyword

```java
public class blah2 extends blah1 {

  void useVariable() {
    super.getVariable(); // get variable
    super.setVariable(1); // set variable
  }

}
```

**EDIT**
As stated by @Pshemo it's legit removing the `super` keyword (and you should do it if you're planning to override the getter and setter in order to use the overriden version) obtaining:

```java
void useVariable() {
    getVariable(); // get variable
    setVariable(1); // set variable
}
```

Anyway the version using `super` lets you understand how you can call the original version of those methods

Comment: The `super.` is unnecessary and potentially harmful if we override those getters in `blah2` class, since most likely we would want to cal overridden versions instead of *original* versions from superclass.